# How to get 'value' attribute of tag <input> in Django?

Tags: django

I have this view function to delete task from ToDo application:

```
def delete_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task = Task.objects.get(pk=request.POST['delete'])
        task.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('todoapp:index'))
    else:
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'tasks': tasks})
```

I get 'value' of tag

Here is my html:

```
<form action="{% url 'todoapp:delete_task' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="{{ task.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

**And my button shows id of task instead of word 'Delete' any ideas how I can get data of tag <input> in another way?**
Thank you advance!!

Comment: I'm not really following, at the bottom of your answer, you say you get the id of the task, but that seems to be exactly what you need, since you usee `pk=request.POST`?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem, Yep I get task.id from value attribute, but in doing so I sacrifice the value attribute as Placeholder for the text 'Delete', and the question is: Can I have value=Delete and still in POST request understand which task to delete? I apologise for my poor English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the [**`value="…"`** <sup>[mdn-doc]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button#button_with_a_value) in an `<input type="button">` is used to show the *text* in the button.

An equivalent way to do this would be to use a `<button>` where you have more freedom to specify the content of the button, so:

```
<form action="{% url 'todoapp:delete_task' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="delete" value="{{ task.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
</form>
```

That being said, typically the primary key is encoded in the *URL*, this ensures that Django will only route the request to your view if such primary key is present.

Your view can also be improved to:

```
from django.shortcut import redirect


def delete_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task = Task.objects.filter(pk=request.POST['delete']).delete()
        return redirect('todoapp:index')
    else:
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'tasks': tasks})
```

---

> **Note**: You can make use of [**`redirect(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) instead
> of first calling [**`reverse(…)`** <sup>[Django]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) and
> then wrap it in a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect).
> The `redirect(…)` function does not only offer a more convenient signature to do this, it also for example will use the
> [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url)
> if you pass it a model object.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simply to pass an additional variable to the view function:

```
def delete_task(request, task_id):
    If request.method == 'POST':
        Task.objects.get(pk=task_id).delete()
        return redirect('todoapp:index')
    else:
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'tasks': tasks})
```

And my html finally value='Delete' !!!

```
<form action="{% url 'todoapp:delete_task' task.id %}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Thank you so much @willeM_VanOnsem, you've dawned on me a solution

Here's what it looked like before and after:
[image]

[image]